# Triangular Connect Wall + Colouring In

Tags: connect-wall

Your task is to divide the 15 words shown into five categories and assign each word the correct colour.

Each category has a different number of words between 1 and 5.
All words within the same category must be the same colour. Different categories do not necessarily have different colours. The top word must be coloured red.

[image]

FUN FACT: The diagram was generated using the excellent tikZ package. It sure beats Microsoft Shapes or SmartArt

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The categories are as follows

> **Category 1:** Words to which we can append **BALL** to create the name of a sport - DODGE(ball), SOFT(ball), CALVIN(ball), BASKET(ball), BASE(ball)
>  **Category 2:** Terms used when discussing [pinball machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_pinball_terms) - BUMPER, TILT, DRAIN, KICKBACK
>  **Category 3:** Tile-matching video games which use balls - [ZUMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zuma_(video_game)), [LUXOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luxor_(video_game)), [BUST A MOVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puzzle_Bobble)
>  **Category 4:** Lawn games involving throwing/rolling heavy balls towards a target ball - BOWLS, [PÉTANQUE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9tanque)
>  **Category 5:** Central to the puzzle - POOL

The categories should be coloured as follows

> **Category 1** - YELLOW
>  **Category 2** - RED
>  **Category 3** - RED
>  **Category 4** - YELLOW
>  **Category 5** - BLACK

This gives the following diagram

> [image]

Which is

> The traditional set up for [English pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight-ball_pool_(British_variation)).

Interesting sidenote

> "Bust a Move" is also a [song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bust_a_Move_(song)) built on a sample by the group *Ballin' Jack* which I thought was a fun connection but irrelevant to the puzzle.

Comment: Too easy, the checkmark is yours!

Comment: Minor nitpick, the question has bowls (which doesn't involve throwing), not boules.

Comment: @fljx woops, I seem to have completely misread that. Edited now, thanks